# what is the relevance of first string parameter in mongoose.model method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nodes

while compiling a schema we use the mongoose.model, I am not able to understand the relevance of first String argument accepted by the model method

```
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

Here the first argument inside model method is 'Kitten' and the second argument is the schema, can I give any name to the first argument?

its not clear in the docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js

> Am I referring the correct docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert our **Schema** into a **Model** we can work with. To do so, we pass it into **mongoose.model(modelName, schema)**:

so you can use any name that you want for **modelName** but it should be meaning full

also valid if you define `userSchema` as model name `User` or `Customer` like:

`mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` then table will be creat with name `users`

**or**

`mongoose.model('Customer', userSchema);` then table will be creat with name `customers`

[see this document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and [this one](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if this piece of info is included in api docs rather that the guide

Comment: from the guide >> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database. The .model() function makes a copy of schema. Make sure that you've added everything you want to schema before calling .model()!

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

The difference between the variable name `Kitten` and the parameter string `"Kitten"` is that `kitten` refers to the model name, and "Kitten" refers to the collection name.

**NOTE:** mongodb will convert the string "Kitten" into a plural form, so you will find the collection named "Kittens" (with '*s*' at the end) inside your mongodb.